# SQLException : Given password did not match password used to create the PooledConnection

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

We have an application which interacts with DB through tomcat datasource.
We have an application to connect to 5 different databases running on the same system.
I have configured 5 data source in context.xml. We have secondary database as well. so it has 10 data source configured in context.xml.

It throws "SQLException : Given password did not match password used to create the PooledConnection." when there is more request.
Password is same for all the databases. I wonder why it can happen when the password is same. I have used "sa" and it is changed to other user to monitor.

Here is the datasource used.

```xml
<Resource auth="Container"     driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS" 
    name="jdbc/DBCPDS" type="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.218.140.8:1433;DatabaseName=SNECDB"/>
        <Resource auth="Container" dataSourceName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/DBCPDS" 
    defaultMaxActive="20" defaultMaxIdle="5" defaultMaxWait="10000" 
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.PerUserPoolDataSourceFactory" 
    logAbandoned="true" name="jdbc/ECDB" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" testOnBorrow="false"type="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.PerUserPoolDataSource" validationQuery="select 1"/>
```

Comment: I have changed testOnBorrow="true" and added testWhileIdle="true"         timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000" to get the object validated.We need to monitor tommorow to check whether this has any impact. Please advice whether it could be one of the reason or not

Comment: Here is the java code which access the datasource                                                objDataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup(dataSourceName);
   try {
    connection = objDataSource.getConnection(userName, password);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    objLogger.error("[" + ucid + "]"
      + "SQLException in connection manager: "
      + e.getMessage());
    UpdateProperty property = new UpdateProperty();
    property.updateStatus(ucid, "cmm.db2");
   }

  }

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28413177/edit) option to add more info to your comment. Do not provide that info in comments, it makes your question harder to read and understand.

Comment: Searching the description of the exception, seems like a bug on the Apache DBCP library that handles the connection pool. This library is used by tomcat. Possible solutions: 1) Update that library in your tomcat installation, 2) Use a different library to implement your database connection pool like C3P0, BoneCP or HikariCP, create and inject the connection pool manually in the application wherever you use it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. is it possible that adding " testOnBorrow="true"" could resolve this issue as the purpose of it is to validate the connection before returning it?. Please advice

Comment: Have you at least made a research on the error message you're receiving? Did you understand why this happens? If you don't, then your attempts to solve it may be in vain e.g. *is it possible that adding " testOnBorrow="true"" could resolve this issue?*.

Comment: Yes. I have made research on it. From the description I do understand It can happen if the password is changed without tomcat restart. This is not possible as the password is same here from day one and user/password only today. The strange part is next request works without any change or restart. This happens once in every few hour and few times in hour during peak time. Let me check on the library as well